# ruby-oci8: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: ruby, oracle

I tried to connect to Oracle DB with the latest **oracle_enhanced**, **ruby-oci8** gems on a Windows 7 x64 PC and it failed as follows:

```
$ ruby oracle_db_connection.rb
oci8.c:654:in oci8lib_230.so: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (OCIError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.2-x64-mingw32/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:142:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:333:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:333:in `new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:393:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:26:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:26:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:9:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:9:in `create'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:156:in `oracle_enhanced_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `table_exists?'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:97:in `get_primary_key'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:85:in `reset_primary_key'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:73:in `primary_key'
        from C:in `primary_key'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:493:in `find_nth_with_limit'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:484:in `find_nth'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:127:in `first'
        from C:in `first'
        from oracle_db_connection.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

I installed Oracle instant client by downloading and unzipped it to

```
**C:\Program Files\Oracle\instantclient_12_1**
```

I added the environment variable **TNS_ADMIN** pointing to **C:\Program Files\Oracle\instantclient_12_1**.
I added TNS_ADMIN to the Path.

When running the simple ruby script:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'oracle_enhanced',
  database: 'my_db_sid',
  host: 'my_db_host',
  port: 1531,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
)


class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'CUSTOMER'
end

puts "First: #{Customer.first}"
```

If I remove the call to the Customer table, I can inspect connection object:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'oracle_enhanced',
  database: 'my_db_sid',
  host: 'my_db_host',
  port: 1531,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
)
puts connection.inspect



#class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
#  self.table_name = 'CUSTOMER'
#end
#
#puts "First: #{Customer.first}"
```

Any idea on what is wrong here ? The script worked previousely fine on other PCs but with other DBs and environement. So the used settings should be fine. 
Thank you.

**Environment**:

- Windows 7 x 64 bits Ruby 2.3
- activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.6.7)
- ruby-oci8 (2.2.2 x64-mingw32)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some different format of `database` section. Here's my config:

```
  adapter: "oracle_enhanced"
  username: "db_user"
  database: "//my.host/my.sid"
  password: "passw0rd"
```

Comment: Changed as asked for: ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'oracle_enhanced',
  database: '//db_host:1531/db_sid',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'userpwd'
) and it failed with the same error :(

Comment: More of that, you should use quotes for passed in values. The same error is also present in README at oracle enhanced gem: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced

Comment: Huh. Did you test your connection with TNSPING http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsping ?

Comment: _> The same error is also present in README at oracle enhanced gem_
No quotes isn't error. Rails `database.yml` not requires quotes for strings.

Comment: OK. First - I'm out of Rails, just a ruby file to run. Second, I copy-pasted the same connection values from sqldevelopper tool which connects fine to the specified DB. Third, I have no TNSNAMES.ORA, nor ORACLE_HOME set. My be that is the problem ?

Comment: As described [here](https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8/blob/4e1c717e993cbe19f279952d2065e7c6ce5968c8/docs/install-instant-client.md), you don't need export ORACLE_HOME if you don't have tnslistener.ora.

Comment: Can you connect via OCI8 without orcale enhanced?
`OCI8.new('user', 'pass', '//my.host:1521/my.sid')`

Comment: Just tried to run require 'oci8'

oci = OCI8.new('user', 'pwd', '//host:1531/db_sid')
puts oci.inspect and got the same error: oci8.c:654:in oci8lib_230.so: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (OCIError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.2-x64-mingw32/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:142:in `initialize'
        from oci_connection.rb:3:in `new'
        from oci_connection.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: I just downloaded Oracle Instant Client Package instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html and unzipped it to my C drive as explained earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to connect to one of 2 databases. They have different settings, at least in Sqldeveloper v 4.1.3.20.

Here are the settings that worked for me (**please note, it is out of Rails context, just a ruby file**):

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'oracle_enhanced',
  host: 'as specified in the field Host name of SQL developer',
  port: 'as specified in the field Port of SQL developer',
  database: 'as specified in the fiels Service name of SQL developer',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'userpassword'
)
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'DEPARTMENTS'
end

puts "First found department: #{Department.first.inspect}"
```

The second database has different settings in SQL developer:

```
- host: some_host_url
- port: some port number
- SID: some SID value
```

The last soltion was to add the following settings:

```
HOST = "your host"
PORT = XXXX #your port number
SID = 'your SID'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        adapter: 'oracle_enhanced',
        database: "(DESCRIPTION=
          (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=#{HOST})(PORT=#{PORT})))
          (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=#{SID}))
        )",
        username: 'user',
        password: 'secret'
      )
```

Hope this helps.